# Creating a transparent overlay in C#

Tags: c#, overlay, global, keyboard-hook, click-through

I'm not sure exactly how to start this project, but my requirements are as follows (for the parts that I'm unsure of how to implement):

- Holding down the Tab key should display the overlay. Letting go of the tab key should hide the overlay. How would I capture this globally? What's the best way to check that the Tab key is still being held down?
- The overlay should display over all other applications. It does not have to display over a full screened application, but it would be optimal to be able to do so.
- Resolution scaling? Not as important, but it would be nice to have the size of the overlay scale based on the user's monitor resolution.

I haven't started this yet, but which project type would be best for this? I was thinking WPF over WindowsForms since it seems to offer a lot more flexibility in terms of presentation. Any advice on the above points would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: that sounds potentially malicious... what exactly is the goal of such an application ?

Comment: You're asking lots of questions in one. Consider splitting each separate aspect into a different question. Also almost all of your 'sub questions' have duplicates here. Use the search function to find things like global hotkeys in C# and passing events through your window to the ones underneath.

Comment: you better start this as a WPF project..

Comment: @phonicUK, There is information concerning global hotkeys, but I haven't seen anything about how to best check if a key is still being held down or not. Is there some OnKeyRelease event that I can listen to? I'm unsure about how to implement this. Edit: Ok, on another search, I've found the answer to my second bullet point. Still need help on the others, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF, you can do it this way:

For the global TAB key handling, at the entry point of your application (usually App.xaml.cs),
run this code:

```
EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(UIElement), UIElement.PreviewKeyUpEvent, new KeyEventHandler(OnPreviewKeyUp));
```

Use (Preview)Key(up/Down)Event as you need it, if you set e.Handled = true in a Preview event handler, the event will stop its routing and nobody else will be able to react to it.

In OnPreviewKeyUp, check that `e.Key == Key.Tab`, and show the overlay window if it is.

The signature of the event handler should look like:

```
private static void OnPreviewKeyUp(object source, KeyEventArgs e)
```

Now for the click-through part, make a Window and set the background of your overlay to `null`:

```
WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="{x:Null}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll try that out sometime later this week when I have time to work on this. I'll accept your answer if it works. Could you explain a bit more on the global TAB key handling though? Would I have to register the OnPreviewKeyDown event as well? Also, do you mean to check e.Key == Key.Tab in the OnPreviewKeyDown event? I want the overlay shown only while the TAB key is pressed.

Comment: You could create the overlay window on the keydown event, and remove it on the keyup event.

Comment: Ok, I have the click-through working, but I can't seem to get the visibility toggle to work. I am using `public static void OnPreviewKeyDown(object source, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
                ((Window1)source).Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public static void OnPreviewKeyUp(object source, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Tab)
                ((Window1)source).Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }`  I registered the events in the main method of App.g.cs. I put breakpoints, but the debugger never hits them.

Comment: App.g.cs is auto-generated, don't touch it